# How to bind two tables to Datagridview using entity framework C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, datagridview

I have two Tables Estate and EstateType. How to bind those two tables to one data grid?
I tried something like this but this doesn't work.

```
 var getAllEst = (from ee in AgencyContext.Estate join eeT in AgencyContext.EstateType
                         on ee.EstateID equals eeT.EstateID select ee).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = getAllEst;
```

Instead of string values EstateType, Landscape, Description it gives me numbers
[image]

As suggested @tpayne84 I'm added new columns but now I get this instead of values:
[image]

This is the code I used:

```
var getAllEst = (from ee in AgencyContext.Estate join eeT in AgencyContext.EstateType
                         on ee.EstateID equals eeT.EstateID select ee).ToList();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn EstateType1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn LandScape1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Description1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        EstateType1.DataPropertyName = "EstateType";
        LandScape1.DataPropertyName = "LandScape";
        Description1.DataPropertyName = "Discription";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(EstateType1);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(LandScape1);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Description1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = getAllEst;
```

Comment: Explain what you mean when you say "this doesn't work."  Do you get an error or just incorrect output?

Comment: I'm updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you are displaying the Foreign Key ID of the referenced object instead of the Property on the Object that you wish to display.

This happens because you are allowing the DataGridView to generate your columns for you.

To remedy this, you will need to create the columns yourself:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
// Where "Name" is the String representation of the Property on the
// Object that you want to display.
nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query

> ```
> var getAllEst = (from ee in AgencyContext.Estate 
>                  join eeT in AgencyContext.EstateType
>                      on ee.EstateID equals eeT.EstateID select ee).ToList();
> ```

will only select `AgencyContext.Estate` objects that have an associated `EstateType` using an inner join...unless your `Estate class` has some navigation property to the `EstateType`. If you have something like:

```
class Estate
{
    // ...other properties

    // I'm guessing the relationship here...
    public virtual EstateType EstateType { get; set; } 
}
```

then you would be able to access the `EstateType` properties through that property.

Unfortunately, `DataGridView` [doesn't seem to support binding to child properties](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a6f33219-8603-4816-9d0d-ee4e5814de68/datagridview-object-data-sources?forum=winformsdatacontrols) so you wouldn't be able to set `column.DataPropertyName = EstateType.SomeProperty`, but you could work around that by overriding `EstateType.ToString()` or handling the `CellFormatting` event on the `DataGridView`.